# How to pass a parameter in Koa middleware?

Tags: koa, koa2, koa-router

So I have this function in Koa, that basically checks if a user can access a specific route.

```
exports.requireRole = async role =>
  async (ctx, next) => {
    const { user } = ctx.state.user;
    try {
      const foundUser = await User.findById(user.id);
      // If the user couldn't be found, return an error
      if (!foundUser) {
        ctx.status = 404;
        ctx.body = { errors: [{ error: ERRORS.USER_NOT_FOUND }] };
      } else {
        // Otherwise, continue checking role
        if (getRole(user.role) >= getRole(role)) {
          await next();
        }

        ctx.status = 403;
        ctx.body = { errors: [{ error: ERRORS.NO_PERMISSION }] };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.throw(500, err);
    }
  };
```

And I want to use it as a middleware:

```
router.delete('/:id', combine([jwtAuth, requireRole(ROLES.ADMIN)]), deleteUser);
```

But then I get an error saying:

**middleware must be a function not object**

This happens only when I try to pass an argument into it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is due to the fact that Promises are objects, and async functions return Promises.  You need to change your initial function to be as follows:

`exports.requireRole = role =>`

instead of

`exports.requireRole = async role =>`

I was going over middleware myself, and ran into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware looks fine, what is `combine`?

Also, since you are using `koa-router` you don't need it.

```
router.delete('/:id', jwtAuth, requireRole(ROLES.ADMIN), deleteUser);
```

Comment: combine is koa-compose which combines multiple middlewares.

Comment: Dont remember exact syntax but could be that compose has variadic parameters insead of an array. Either way, you don’t need it.